# Why React complains about key not provided when it is there?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing

I'm trying to get rid off the following warning from React:

```
console.error
      Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
      
      Check the render method of `UsersList`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
          at h4
          in UsersList (at UsersList.test.jsx:28)

       5 |
       6 |   return (
    >  7 |     <>
         |     ^
       8 |     {props.users.map(user => <h4 className='box title is-4' key={user.id}>{user.username}</h4>)}
       9 |     </>
      10 |     )
```

As you can see unique key is being given to each `h4` element.
Why the test runner keeps complaining and pointing at React fragment tag ?
The `h4` element doesn't have any children.

Thank you.

Comment: Your code is right! There should be a duplicated key! Are you completely sure that your keys are unique !?

Comment: Positive. I just rendered those keys into my app and they're all different. Super weird.

Comment: Mmmm, try using toString() function: key={id.toString()} or using a map index like this: users.map((user, index)..

Comment: Need minimal, reproducibe example